# MDX -No Sales over 30 days

Tags: ssas, mdx, measure

I'd like to get the product with zero sales over 30 days. E.g. Below is my expected result:
Store,Product,Days
Store1, product1, 33
Store1, product2, 100
Store2, product5, 96
Store34, product14, 78
Store100, product9, 47

So I wrote below query：

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[Zero Sales Days] 
AS 
COUNT(
     FILTER(
            NONEMPTY( [Calendar].[Date].[Day],[Measures].[POS Qty])                   
             , ( [Measures].[POS Qty]=0)
            ) 
 )

SELECT 
([Store].[Store].[Store],[product].[product].[product]) on 1,
([MEASURES].[Zero Sales Days]) ON 0
FROM [testcube]
```

The problem is: How to filter the case: days of zero sales<30

Thanks,
Nia

---

I did some change and then ran against my DB. 
I got nothing if I added the where cause. If not, the result is '#Error'.

I need not select any time related dimension. What I want to do for the report is: select store and product dimension, and define a calculated measure to get the count. Boyan, I will be really appreciated it if you can need the detailed the query for it.

Answer (score 2):

The function [LastPeriods](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/LastPeriods.html) is what you're looking for:

```
 WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Zero Sales Days] 
  AS COUNT(
        FILTER([Calendar].[Date].[Day], 
          SUM( LastPeriods(30, [Calendar].[Date].currentmember),[Measures].[POS Qty]) 
          = 0 )
        ) 
 SELECT 
  ([Store].[Store].[Store],[product].[product].[product]) on 1,
  ([MEASURES].[Zero Sales Days]) ON 0
 FROM [testcube]
```

Comment: Thanks, I used it and got 0 for all stores and products.

Answer (score 1):

The following query works against Adventure Works and shows you the products with no sales for over 30 days from the date in the WHERE clause back:

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[Number of Periods With No Sales] AS
    Iif(([Date].[Date].CurrentMember, [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])=0,
        ([Date].[Date].PrevMember, [Measures].[Number of Periods With No Sales])+1,
        NULL
    )
MEMBER [Measures].[Number of > 30 Periods With No Sales] AS
    Sum(
        Iif([Measures].[Number of Periods With No Sales] > 30,
            [Measures].[Number of Periods With No Sales],
            NULL
        )
    )
SELECT
{
    [Measures].[Number of > 30 Periods With No Sales]
} ON 0,
NON EMPTY {
    [Product].[Product Categories].[Product]
} ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[860]
```

You will need to re-work it (change the dimension/measure names) to get it to work against your db. Please let me know if you need a query which can give you all products regardless of the date, which have at least one period with more than 30 days with no sales (e.g. max period with no sales, or an arbitrary such period). This will require a few changes. Also, since the query is using recursion it may be slow - if it is too slow we can see how to improve its performance - something which may require changes to your data model to support this bit of analytics.

Comment: I need not select any time related dimension. What I want to do for the report is: select store and product dimension, and define a calculated measure to get the count.

Comment: So for a store and a product you want the count of days with no sales if over 30? And this is over the whole time dimension? Regardless of whether the days are continuous? If so, then try:

WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[Count of Days with no Sales] AS
    ([Date].[Date].[Date]-NonEmpty([Date].[Date].[Date], [Measures].[Sales])).Count
MEMBER [Measures].[Count of Days with no Sales for more than 30 Days] AS
    Iif([Measures].[Count of Days with no Sales] > 30, [Measures].[Count of Days with no Sales], NULL)

Comment: Thanks man! E.g in the store A, the product1 was sold on 7/1/2011 (Last sales date), after that it was not sold anymore. Then the value for it will be 32, we need show a value '32' for store A and product1. But in the same store A, the last sales date for the product2 was 7/25/2011, the total no sales days after last sales date will be smaller than 30, then the product2 need be shown in the report. I hope I explained my quesion clearly.

Comment: One problem - what is the current date? Do you have a Current Date attribute in your dimension? If so, then the query in my first post (the larger one) will work just fine as long as you place the Current Date in the where clause.

Comment: Ok, have a look at how it can be done in the DSV here: http://www.beeii.com/?p=495. Once you are ready with a working one you can use it in the WHERE clause like this (from the post): Exists([Date].[Date].[Date].MEMBERS,[Date].[Is Current Day].&[True])